# C++ struct binary file

Tags: c++

Hello guys I am new to c++ programming
I have saved struct in binary file..
But when try to read it application is crashing
Here is my code

```
struct Person
{
    string name;
    int age;

};
void main()
{
    Person p;
    ifstream is("person.data",ios::binary);
    is.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p));


}
```

Comment: You need to have a look into ***serialization***. You cannot save complex classes as binary images to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `sizeof(p)`.

The `string` class is of variable length. This means it is essentially a struct with a pointer in it to some other characters in the heap. Attempting to read the string in via struct won't work. You have to put all the characters in the struct itself, or it will just read in a (now-dead) pointer to somewhere in the heap and likely cause a segmentation fault.

Try this:

```
struct Person
{
    char name[40];
    int age;

};
void main()
{
    Person p;
    ifstream is("person.data",ios::binary);
    is.read((char*)&p,sizeof(p));
}
```

Then use c string functions instead of C++ ones found in `cstring` or `string.h`.

Honestly, though, you may want to listen to @πάντα ῥεῖ . You're trying to *serialize* C structs. Reading data in via struct is a very "C" thing to do, but you're mixing "C++" classes into that. The two paradigms don't mix very well. [BOOST has a serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), if you really want to serialize C++ classes I would start there.